# Preprocessor Stringizing Operator with String Literal Prefixes

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, string-literals, stringification

So I want to do the traditional thing to do with the stringizing operator in a macro:

```
#define FOO(x) foo(#x, (x))
```

However I need to use a string literal prefix: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal
Which is a problem because if I need a UTF-32 string literal I try to do this:

```
#define FOO(x) foo(U#x, (x))
```

But gcc 4.9.2 complains:

> error: 'U' was not declared in this scope

Is there a way to make the compiler treat the `U` as a prefix to the stringized macro variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [use concatenation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90cd236f043ff172):

```
#define CONCAT2(x, y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x, y) CONCAT2(x, y)
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x

#define FOO(x) foo(CONCAT(U, STRINGIZE(x)), (x))
```

The extra indirection, besides being good if you pass a macro that should be evaluated first, is "needed" because of N3936 §16.3.2 [cpp.stringize]/2, which says:

> The order of evaluation of # and ## operators is unspecified.

Comment: @leemes, You're good as long as the result is a *preprocessing-token*. `U"abc"` is a *string-literal*, which is a *preprocessing-token*.

Comment: @leemes The `U"abc"` string literal is not defined at all on Visual Studio T.T

Comment: @JonathanMee, [It is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx) in the 2015 preview!