# Macro Operator List

Tags: c++, macros, operators, c-preprocessor, standard-library

I know about Macro's Stringizing operator (`#`) and I recently learned about the (`##`) Concatenation operator: [Preprocessor Stringizing Operator with String Literal Prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850088/preprocessor-stringizing-operator-with-string-literal-prefixes)

Are there any other macro operators that are available to me?

I know that Boost has a pretty extensive suite that they've put together, however for the purposes of this question I'm just asking about Macro operator support defined by the standard.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor

Comment: @Cyber So from this list it looks like the conclusive answer is, "No". There are no other Macro operators. Maybe post this as an answer?

Comment: @Cyber I've gone ahead and summarized your link into an answer cause that's as close as I can find to an official NO answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned by [Cyber's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031175/macro-operator-list#comment48178647_30031175) the Sringizing ( `#` ) and Concatenation Operators ( `##` ) are the only macro operators defined in C++: [Macro Operator List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30031175/macro-operator-list#comment48178647_30031175)

This link also illiterates the list of predefined macros that the standard defines. Which are also available for use in macros, though they're not actually operators.

If you're not into cross platform compatibility it may also be worth noting that Visual C++ provides one non-standard operator, the Charizing Operator ( `#@` ): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91tt6dfs.aspx