# C Macro should expand as char* in one place and wchar* in another place with L character

Tags: c, macros, char, widechar

I am looking for help with writing a C macro that expands into char* macro in one place and wchar_t* macro in another place.

Eg:

```
#define MACRO_STRING "Macro String"
```

to atomic section with function calls:

```
{
    function1(L"Macro String");
    function2("Macro String");
}
```

**function1** always accepts wide characters `wchar_t *`, while **function2** always accepts `char *`.

In most places in my code I am calling **function1** immediately followed by **function2**. Throughout my code, the string "Macro String" is a constant. But one function takes input as `wchar*` while the other takes input as `char*`.

Need help in expanding the macro differently in the two functions

Comment: Two functions often called together with different versions of the same data sounds like both a code smell and an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and easy solution, with no extra macros:

- Use `MACRO_STRING` directly when you need `char *`.
- Use `L"" MACRO_STRING` when you need `wchar_t *`.

Comment: This is a quick and easy solution indeed, and works because (1) adjacent string literals in C are merged into a single object and (2) only one of them has to have the `L` prefix for that whole object to be a wide string.

Comment: Thanks. This answer has made my day.

Answer (score 3):

A macro does not know its surrounding context - that is to say, it can not be made to behave differently depending on where it is used. Macros are really just a form of [text replacement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace), with only a few extra capabilities.

You must either wrap the macro in another macro which prefixes it, or change the function call to be a macro which hides this implementation detail.

Note that the second option creates mental overhead within your codebase where you must remember to use `f1_lit` **only** when you pass a *character string literal* to be automagically adjusted to a *wide string literal*. For actual *wide string literals* (and pointers to buffers) you must call `f1` directly.

```
#define CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
#define L(x) CONCAT(L, x)
#define f1_lit(x) f1(L(x))

#define MYSTRING "hello"

void f1(const wchar_t *s) {
    /* ... */
}

void f2(const char *s) {
    /* ... */
}

int main(void) {
    f1(L(MYSTRING));

    f1_lit(MYSTRING);
    f2(MYSTRING);
}
```

Results of preprocessing (`gcc -E`):

```
f1(L"hello");

f1(L"hello");
f2("hello");
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850088/preprocessor-stringizing-operator-with-string-literal-prefixes) Q&A for additional details on why the macro indirection is needed.

It would probably be best to just have two different macros for both types of string literals, and use the appropriate one where needed.

```
#define MYSTRING "hello"
#define MYSTRING_W L"hello"
```

Then again, the pattern in the question itself is dubious as you've not provided a reasoning behind calling two such similarly formed functions, only a vague notion. Where else are those functions used, and would this not be something better handled at runtime?

Possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) material.

Comment: Thanks @Oka. I will keep this solution in mind. At the moment, I don't have the coding freedom to change the code to use two macros. But this explanation has expanded my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another macro which adds the `L` prefix:

```
#define ELL(s) L ## s
```

and wrap your macro using the `ELL` macro:

```
function1(ELL(MACRO_STRING));
```

Comment: I want a string macro to expand with the L.

Comment: @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy' That's impossible. You can't have a macro expand to different things, it will either be one or the other.

Comment: In the code the macro is already defined, but while using the macros needs to have L in one of the functions.

Comment: Can you help me reframe the question, in case it is not clear?

Comment: you can use certain kind of if else statement to differentiate between them.

Comment: @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy': Can you explain why this answer does not suit your needs? It lets you use your existing macro, and attaches an L. (I don't know if it works with Visual C, though.)

Comment: Actually, it won't work because you need an extra level of macro indirection. `define ELL(s) ELL_(L,s)` / `define ELL_(pfx,s) pfx ## s`. As written, you'll get `LMACRO_STRING`.

Comment: @GaneshKamath-'CodeFrenzy': A macro cannot expand to two different things depending on where it is used; the preprocessor just isn't that smart.  It will *always* expand to `"Macro String"`.  If you need to prepend an `L` when passing it to `function1`,  then HolyBlackCat's answer is the easiest way to do it.